# Tmux: Errors when creating a new pane

Tags: tmux

Whenever I open a new window pane, I receive some weird printf errors.
Tmux works just fine but these errors are annoying.
Any way to fix it?

```
dr_preinst:printf:2: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:5: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:10: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:2: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:5: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:10: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:2: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:5: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:10: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:2: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:5: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:10: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:2: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:5: not enough arguments
dr_preinst:printf:10: not enough arguments
```

I tried to find any file name *dr_preinst* to see whats the problem but none found on my system.

Comment: When did this start to happen?

Comment: does the issue occur if you use an empty tmux.conf?

Comment: It happens whenever I start a new terminal in tmux.
Yes, I use an empty tmux.conf

Comment: *When* did this start to happen though? What shell do you use?

Comment: You can accept the one answer if it working for you. (It's worked for me)

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the solution. The issue was not with Tmux but with Nobara linux while using Zsh and Tmux.

It's caused due to a hack to fix Davinci resolve and Payday 2.

It may also be present on other distros, but I haven't checked it.

The culptrit is the $BASH_COMMAND. As you are most probably using a non-bash shell, and the $BASH_COMMAND is not shell agnostic.

The issue is at the `/etc/profile` in the dr_preinst function. Just type in the terminal:

`sudo nano /etc/profile`

Find this function:

```bash
# (1) This is a hack to override Davinci Resolve glib2 with systemwide version via shortcut modification post-install
# (2) Payday 2 native OpenGL is broken, use zink to force OpenGL -> Vulkan

function dr_preinst() {
    # (1)
    if printf $BASH_COMMAND | grep DaVinci_Resolve | grep Linux; then
        PROMPT_COMMAND=nobara-resolve-wizard
    fi
    if printf $BASH_COMMAND | grep nobara-resolve-wizard; then
        PROMPT_COMMAND=""
    fi

    # (2)
    if printf $BASH_COMMAND | grep payday2_release; then
        export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=zink
    fi
}

trap dr_preinst DEBUG
```

And comment it out to fix this bug.

It must look like this:

```bash
# (1) this is a hack to override Davinci Resolve glib2 with systemwide version via shor>
# (2) payday 2 native opengl is broken, use zink to force opengl->vulkan

#function dr_preinst() {
# (1)
#       if printf $BASH_COMMAND | grep DaVinci_Resolve | grep Linux; then
#               PROMPT_COMMAND=nobara-resolve-wizard
#        fi
#       if printf $BASH_COMMAND | grep nobara-resolve-wizard; then
#               PROMPT_COMMAND=""
#       fi
#
# (2)
#        if printf $BASH_COMMAND | grep payday2_release; then
#                export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=zink
#        fi
#}
#trap dr_preinst DEBUG
```

After that just save the file and try it again.

If the issue persists try logging out and back in or reboot.

Edit

Possible Shell-agnostic solution (in case you need to use these sofware just replace the dr_preinst function with this):

```bash
# (1) this is a hack to override Davinci Resolve glib2 with systemwide version via shor>
# (2) payday 2 native opengl is broken, use zink to force opengl->vulkan

dr_preinst() {
    # (1)
    if ps -o args= -p $$ | grep DaVinci_Resolve | grep Linux; then
        PROMPT_COMMAND=nobara-resolve-wizard
    fi
    if ps -o args= -p $$ | grep nobara-resolve-wizard; then
        PROMPT_COMMAND=""
    fi

    # (2)
    if ps -o args= -p $$ | grep payday2_release; then
        export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=zink
    fi
}

trap dr_preinst DEBUG
```

In this modified version, the ps command is used to retrieve the arguments of the current process ($$) and then grep is used to check if specific strings are present in the command line. This approach should work in most Unix-like shells.

But i haven't tested it and it may cause other issues I'm not currently aware.